# How to Create count bubble with @Html.ActionLink in mvc with jquery mobile

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created Count bubble in button in mvc4 with jquery mobile. Below Code

```
<a href="url.html" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
 DK-02<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">11</span></a>
```

Gives

[image]

Now how to create similar look and feel button using  @Html.ActionLink razor syntax?

```
 @Html.ActionLink("DK-02","test","home")
```

**UPDATED**

With the help of u guys i solved my 80% problem. what i did is

```
<div class="ui-grid-c">
    @for (int j = 1; j < myPutaway.Count + 1; j++)
    {
        if **(j == 1)**
        {
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a href="@Url.Action("test", "DirectPutaway")" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
                @myPutaway[j].ReceivingLane.ToString() <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color: white; color: #52616D">@myPutaway[j].NoOfMuf.ToString() </span></a>
        </div>
        }
        else if **(j == 2)**
        {
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a href="@Url.Action("test", "DirectPutaway")" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
                @myPutaway[j].ReceivingLane.ToString() <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color: white; color: #52616D">@myPutaway[j].NoOfMuf.ToString()</span></a>
        </div>
        }
        else if **(j == 3)**
        {
        <div class="ui-block-c">
            <a href="@Url.Action("test", "DirectPutaway")" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
                @myPutaway[j].ReceivingLane.ToString() <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color: white; color: #52616D">@myPutaway[j].NoOfMuf.ToString()</span></a>
        </div>
        }
        else if **(j == 4)**
        {
        <div class="ui-block-d">
            <a href="@Url.Action("test", "DirectPutaway")" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
                @myPutaway[j].ReceivingLane.ToString() <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color: white; color: #52616D">@myPutaway[j].NoOfMuf.ToString()</span></a>
        </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

[image]

I got it but i hardcorded j==1,2,3,4 to set css class  ,,, which is need to display 4*4 grid. but instead of hard cording how i can make it dynamic. so my 1st value wil get class A and second Class B. .etc

Comment: What's your actual problem here: setting the attributes, creating the nested `<span>` or setting the URL for your `a` element?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **@Url.Action** to put the url in **href** attribute of `a`:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("test","home")' class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
DK-02
<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">11</span>
</a>
```

or if you only want to go with Html helper method, then you have to write you own Custom Html Helper.

You can see how to create in this [**tutorial**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Comment: dude  thanks lot. u solved my 80% problem. please see updated post. I waiting for ur reply.